# Converting the date time to display milliseconds in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, formats

I want to show the milliseconds, but ToString shows the milliseconds as 00000.

I am providing the code below, with the output at each step.

1. `String currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");`

   Output - 7/27/2011 3:05:31 PM
2. `System.DateTime dateTime = System.DateTime.Parse(currentDateTime);`

   Output - 7/27/2011 3:05:31 PM
3. `String dateTimeStr = dateTime.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff", "en-US");`

Output -  03.05.32.000000

I want to show the output with the milliseconds , eg 03.05.32.33456

If I used ParseExact instead of Parse, I am getting an exception. I know that I can use TryParseExact, but that solution might not be suitable , as I need a generic solution to this problem .

Can someone help me in this.

Thanks in advance.
Sujay

Comment: I guess that the third option is correct. Probably the content of the DateTime structure has the millisecs equals to zero.

Comment: No the milliseconds are not zero. Please look at the accepted answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. The third assignment is correct, while the first two have no sense. Why are you using all of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the same dateTime object that you previously built from a string ("7/27/2011 3:05:31 PM" without any milliseconds), you're losing the milliseconds.

If you were to convert Now to a string directly, you would not lose the milliseconds:

```
String dateTimeStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff", "en-US");
```

Answer (score 8):

Not sure why you are moving from DateTime -> string -> DateTime
This should display milliseconds

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff")
```

Please edit the post if you are not looking on these lines for additional info

Comment: Your code wont display millisecond. Please read my post carefully.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you first serialize the DateTime to string using the standard "G" format, which doesn't have miliseconds. So sure, you get 000000 later when you parse this string back:

```
        String currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
        Console.WriteLine(currentDateTime);

        System.DateTime dateTime = System.DateTime.Parse(currentDateTime);

        Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff"));
```

Comment: Peter - Please see the output of 3. I had also used dateTime.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff", "en-US"); , but I get a wrong output. The millisecond are 0000.

Comment: Are you talking about the serialization , yes I did . I want the output without serialization.